# ionic - side-menu doesn't start opened

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I need to open the menu automatically when navigate to a specific page.

but the event is ignored.

I created the menu controller:

```
.controller('MenuController', function ($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
    $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
        $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
    }; })
```

and the specific page controller:

```
.controller('Sem_ConsultasCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.toggleLeft();
    $scope.btn = function () { $scope.toggleLeft(); }

})
```

in my specific page i have a directive ng-click="btn()" wich works (toggles side-menu when click on button).
but if I call ' $scope.toggleLeft(); ' outside of btn() to automatically open the side menu when navigate to specific page nothing happens.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :) FYI: good practice - include jsFiddle / jsBin / plnkr - so it is easier for others to help...

Comment: I already found the solution, but because Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. I still can't publish the answer. After this period I'll submit the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>I found the problem:</del>

<del>when I call '$scope.toggleLeft();' outside of btn() the page/template still has not loaded/rendered the DOM. and when I click on button (btn()) works because DOM is already rendered.</del>

<del>to automatically open the side-menu I need to only call '$scope.toggleLeft();' when DOM is already and for achieve that I need to define a Watcher wich do something when occurs some modification to my template:</del>

```
    $timeout(function () {
        $scope.toggleLeft();
    });
```

<del>$timeout(function () { //runs after DOM is render} );</del>

<del>This way, is working :)</del>

EDIT:

I was going through my answers and I noticed that this answer was not correct.

calling $timeout triggers a digest cycle that captures differences in the DOM and updates it.
other events like clicking a button or writing in a input text triggers a digest cycle, thats why the changes only happened when clicked the button